# End-to-end encryption Flutter + Firebase real-time database

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, aes, end-to-end-encryption

I am making a chat application where:

1. A user can be in a group with multiple other users.
2. All messages must be encrypted with end-to-end

I am using `firebase-realtime-database` to store data.

---

#### What I have

- Randomly generated secret key for every user

  ```dart
  String generateEncryptionKey(int len) {
      var r = Random();
      String randomString = String.fromCharCodes(List.generate(len,
                                  (index) => r.nextInt(33) + 89));
      return randomString;
  }
  ```

This is probably wrong. I would need clarification if I need to get a `derived key` from the user's password or if this is sufficient.

---

#### What I need

- Alice sends a message: I need it to be encrypted with a key that is also accessible by any other participant in the group (`shared-secret key`)
- Bob wants to read this message: I need to decrypt this with the `shared-secret key`

The `shared-secret key` shares something in common with every personal key, right? So the messages encrypted by any of the participants can be decrypted by any other.

How can I generate the `shared-secret key`?

---

### Code Blocks Needed

```dart
generateKeyPair() {
    // Generate a private - public keypair for each user
    // ...somehow used to make the `shared-secret key`?
}

generateSharedSecretKey() {
    // Saved to database as the group's shared secret key.
    // only participants can use it to decrypt messages
}

sendMessage() {
    // 1. Encrypt the message (**code needed**)...using
    //    which combination of keys?
    // 2. Save to database (I already handle this)
}

receiveMessage() {
    // 1. Read from database (I already handle this)
    // 2. Decrypt the message (**code needed**)...using
    //    which combination of keys?
}
```

---

#### Considerations

- Multiple users (so many keys)
- It doesn't need to be super secure (just the bare minimum is enough)
- A user can have an account on multiple devices

---

I have read about the [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), key pairs, etc. But I don't really understand all the concepts as I am quite new.

I would need:

1. Clarification on basic end-to-end encryption concepts (in case something in my explanation was wrong)
2. Simple code samples of every key generation step
3. The code blocks have to work no matter which user is sending a message or receiving. That dynamism is what confuses me. How can you encrypt something taking into account that **any of 50 users can read it?**

I just want encryption of simple data (strings) with multiple users through a database. Is there is an easier way than end-to-end?

Comment: would be great if you could add some code, even if its to examplify.

Comment: @AlexRintt I have edited the answer to make it better. I hope it helps!

Comment: I feel like this is very complicated to achieve, I hope there is a simple way to encrypt messages with multiple users...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Group Chat**

First the group admin (or whoever creates the group) must generate a single key for the group. This uses symmetric encryption where a single key is used for decryption and encryption. This key should be shared with all the participants.

[image]

When a participant wants to send the message, it is encrypted using this key and sent to the server, which simply retransmits it to the participants inbox.

[image]

Since user 2 and 3 already have the shared secret key, they decrypt it client side.
There are many choices for this kind of encryption, you can google any "Symmetric Encryption Algorithm" (Eg: AES) and pick one that is available on pub.dev.

Things to Note:

1. For server side retransmitting, you could use a simple firebase
   cloud function or eliminate the server entirely (not recommended) by allowing the client to send the messages to each participant

**EDIT**:
If you want to encrypt the transport of the Shared Secret Key, you could leverage your existing 1 to 1 architecture and the group admin can send the key to each of the participants by encrypting using the participants public key (which of course they will decrypt on their end). As long as you handle the sendGroupSharedSecretKeyToParticipants() properly on senders side and onReceiveGroupSharedSecretKey() on receivers end, you should be fine. This may complicate things a tad bit (handling of sharing the key differently from a typical chat message) but this would be a simple way to do it.

**1 to 1 Chat**

Each user can have a private key and a public key, messages are sent by encrypting using the receivers public key and the receiver will decrypt it using their own private key, pretty basic stuff which you've already figured out or refer to @Jabbar's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74809596/4481095

Comment: Thanks! How do all users have the shared secret key without saving it to the database??

Comment: Because it would be very easy to use AES encryption, however all users should have the same key, and this needs to be achieved without sharing the key through databases because it could be intercepted or read by the admin.

Comment: I added an edit under group chat with a way to handle this transit, let me know if that works out for you

Comment: so @Koushik Boinepally I would need to generate a Private-Public Keypair for each user, from which I would use the public part to transmit the shared secret key? Do you recommend any package or code to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think if you fully understand end-to-end encryption you will easily do this.

Here is a diagram to explain public/private keys in simple terms:

[image]

So for example **User A** wants to receive a secure message from **User B**:

1. **User A** will generate a public/private key pair. The private key is kept locally with **User A**, and no one else has access to this.
2. **User A** will share only the **public key** when anyone wants to send User A a message.
3. **Public key** is like an open suitcase with a secret code (private key)
4. **User B** wants to send a secure message to **User A**
5. **User B** will use the public key to encrypt the message (put the message inside the suitcase and close it) and send it back to **User A**
6. The message will need the **private key** to be decrypted
7. Only **User A** has the **Private key**, so **User A** is the only one who could see the message. Not even **User B** can decrypt the message after encryption

Comment: Thanks for the response @Jabbar. A couple of doubts. You say 'Not even User B can decrypt the message after encryption.' This is not what I need, I need for the user who sends this to be able to see it too. Is this achievable? And, MOST importantly, this is a group chat. So which public key, from the 20 users in my supposed chat group that have key pairs, will I use to encrypt the single entry of that data in my database?

Comment: In other words, could you extend this answer to cover the case where User A wants to send a message to User B, C, D, etc... at the same time?

Comment: [Third person singular](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=0m38s) in the image. Missing "s"es.

Comment: What is *"doe"* in *"secret doe"*?  A *"secret door"* does not fit the context with *"open suitcase"*.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with the *[crypto](https://pub.dev/packages/crypto)* Flutter package, so with the help of this package you can create a key which will satisfy your requirement and you can manage for each and every user. You can also check out the below package which is published by the *dart.dev* team.

Here is a code snippet from the above package also just for convenience.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

void main() {
  var key = utf8.encode('p@ssw0rd');
  var bytes = utf8.encode("foobar");

  var hmacSha256 = Hmac(sha256, key); // HMAC-SHA256
  var digest = hmacSha256.convert(bytes);

  print("HMAC digest as bytes: ${digest.bytes}");
  print("HMAC digest as hex string: $digest");
}
```