# In firebase, can the developer see the users' content?

Tags: java, android, firebase

i just started android development. i realized something while developing andorid. i can see the contents etc. entered by users in firebase. is this the same for other applications?

If you know anything about this, could you tell me about it?

Comment: Firebase has 18+ products, so I recommend editing your question to tell us explicitly which of these products you are asking about.

Comment: Anyone who is appropriately permissioned in a Google Cloud (Firebase) project can see all data from all products in use. It's not limited to "the developer".  The person who created the project could also give access to others, who could in turn give access to even more people.  They could also take that data and send it to other parties if they wish.  This is why applications have terms of service and privacy policies in place - to give users some sense of how their data is being used. As a user, you should also read these things if you're concerned about the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app stores content on behalf of your users in one of Firebase's content storage product (Firestore, Realtime Database, Cloud Storage, and more), then you as the developer can indeed see that content.

If you want to prevent this, you will have to encrypt the content before writing it to Firebase, and store the decryption key somewhere outside of Firebase. Search for [Firebase end to end encryption](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+end+to+end+encryption) to learn more about this, including these previous questions:

- [Is it necessary to encrypt chat messages before storing it into firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47845084/is-it-necessary-to-encrypt-chat-messages-before-storing-it-into-firebase)
- [End-to-end encryption Flutter + Firebase real-time database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74766374/end-to-end-encryption-flutter-firebase-real-time-database)
- [End to end encryption with Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48393557/end-to-end-encryption-with-firestore)

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much normal. Developers need to see user data when developing and debugging code. Although you are asking about Firebase, the principal applies to all database systems.

But in a production system access to production user data is often restricted on a "need to access" basis. Typically only developers chasing data related bugs and database administrators responsible for the health of the database will have access.

The mechanism for controlling access is typically two level:

- You need network access to the database server and access to the port on which the database runs. Firewalling is the tool that controls this.
- You need the credentials required to open the database connection. Typically this will involve a user name plus password or possibly a certificate.

So in short, if you have access to the database you have an excellent chance of reading and possibly modifying user data. Note that most database engines have further access control mechanisms - for example encrypted columns. Also the application may further restrict access. A common example is storing password hashes rather than plaintext passwords.